# Change font size for a TextView widget in a running Gtk3 Perl app

Tags: perl, gtk3

I'm trying to modify the font size, in a TextView widget, in a running Perl application and I'm having a difficult time of it. Here's one of my attempts(the relevant code is in the function setFontSize).

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use feature qw(state);
use local::lib;

use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;

use constant MAX_FONT_SIZE => 200;
use constant MIN_FONT_SIZE => 12;
use constant FONT_UNIT => 4;

use Glib qw(TRUE FALSE);
use Gtk3 qw(init);
use Pango;

sub killKey {
    my ($object, $event) = @_;
    my $c = lc chr ($event->keyval);
    Gtk3->main_quit if $c eq 'q';
    FALSE;
}

sub setFontSize {
    my ($tView, $font_size) = @_;
    my $pCont = $tView->get_pango_context();
    my $fDescr = $pCont->get_font_description();
    $fDescr->set_absolute_size($font_size * Pango::SCALE);
    my $buf = $tView->get_buffer();
    my $end = $buf->get_end_iter();
    my $start = $buf->get_start_iter();
    my $str = $buf->get_text($start, $end, TRUE);
    my $newBuf = Gtk3::TextBuffer->new();
    $newBuf->set_text($str);
    #$buf->set_text($buf->get_text($start, $end, TRUE), -1);
    $tView->set_buffer($newBuf);
    STDOUT->print("called: ", $fDescr->to_string(),"\n");
#   {
#       no strict "refs";
#       
#       for my $elem (sort keys %{ref($fDescr)."::"}) {
#           STDOUT->print("${elem}\n");
#       }
#   }
}

sub catchScroll {
    my ($object, $event, $tView) = @_;

    state $font_size = 40;

    my $dir = $event->direction;
    my ($ctrl, $mod) = @{$event->state};
    if ($ctrl eq q<control-mask> && $mod eq q<mod2-mask>) {
        if ($dir eq q<up>) {
            $font_size += FONT_UNIT if $font_size < MAX_FONT_SIZE;
            setFontSize($tView, $font_size);
            return FALSE;
        }elsif ($dir eq q<down>) {
            $font_size -= FONT_UNIT if $font_size > MIN_FONT_SIZE;
            setFontSize($tView, $font_size);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    FALSE;
}

my $window = Gtk3::Window->new(q<toplevel>);
my $scrWin = Gtk3::ScrolledWindow->new();
my $tView = Gtk3::TextView->new();
my $provider = Gtk3::CssProvider->new();

$provider->load_from_path("the.css");
my $style = $tView->get_style_context();
$style->add_provider($provider, 600);

my $str = qx(perldoc -T -t -f split 2>&1);

my $buf = $tView->get_buffer();
$buf->set_text($str);
my $sIter = $buf->get_start_iter();
$buf->place_cursor($sIter);
#$tView->set_editable(FALSE);

$window->add_events(q<GDK_KEY_PRESS_MASK>);
$window->add_events(q<GDK_SCROLL_MASK>);

$window->signal_connect(delete_event => sub{Gtk3->main_quit; FALSE});
$window->signal_connect(key_press_event => \&killKey);
$window->signal_connect(scroll_event => \&catchScroll, $tView);

$window->set_border_width(0);
$window->fullscreen();
$window->set_decorated(FALSE);

$scrWin->add($tView);
$window->add($scrWin);

$window->show_all;

Gtk3->main;
```

I can hack the font values from the provider and it works perfectly... Kind of makes you wonder why the Gtk3 folks don't have that functionality available for these types of problems.

the.css

```
text {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); 
    color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
}

textview {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

The final version: I added CSS::Tiny to handle the css in provider and added functionality to freeze the vertical scroll bar while I modify the font size with Ctrl+mouse wheel.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use feature qw(state);
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;

use constant MAX_FONT_SIZE => 200;
use constant MIN_FONT_SIZE => 20;
use constant FONT_UNIT => 4;
use constant FONT_START_SIZE => 40;

use CSS::Tiny;

use Glib qw(TRUE FALSE);
use Gtk3 qw(init);

sub killKey {
    my ($object, $event) = @_;
    my $c = lc chr ($event->keyval);
    Gtk3->main_quit if $c eq 'q';
}

sub changeFontSize {
    my ($style, $provider, $font_size) = @_;
    my $cssStr = $provider->to_string();
    my $css = CSS::Tiny->new();
    $css = CSS::Tiny->read_string($cssStr);
    $css->{textview}->{q<font-size>} = "${font_size}px";

    $style->remove_provider($provider);
    $provider = Gtk3::CssProvider->new();
    $provider->load_from_data($css->write_string());
    $style->add_provider($provider, 600);
}

sub catchScroll {
    my ($object, $event, $data) = @_;
    my ($style, $provider, $vadj) = @{$data};
    my ($ctrl, $mod) = @{$event->state};
    my $dir = $event->direction;

    my $retval = Gtk3::get_current_event();

    state $font_size = FONT_START_SIZE;

    if ($ctrl eq q<control-mask> && $mod eq q<mod2-mask>) {
        if ($dir eq q<up>) {
            $font_size += FONT_UNIT if $font_size < MAX_FONT_SIZE;
            changeFontSize($style, $provider, $font_size);
        }elsif ($dir eq q<down>) {
            $font_size -= FONT_UNIT if $font_size > MIN_FONT_SIZE;
            changeFontSize($style, $provider, $font_size);
        }else {
        }
        $vadj->set_value(0.0);
    }
    FALSE;
}

my $window = Gtk3::Window->new(q<toplevel>);
my $scrWin = Gtk3::ScrolledWindow->new();
my $tView = Gtk3::TextView->new();
my $provider = Gtk3::CssProvider->new();

$provider->load_from_path(q<the.css>);
my $style = $tView->get_style_context();
$style->add_provider($provider, 600);

my $str = qx(perldoc -T -t -f split 2>&1);

my $buf = $tView->get_buffer();
$buf->set_text($str);
my $sIter = $buf->get_start_iter();
$buf->place_cursor($sIter);
$tView->set_editable(FALSE);

$window->add_events(q<GDK_KEY_PRESS_MASK>);
$window->add_events(q<GDK_SCROLL_MASK>);


$window->signal_connect(delete_event => sub{Gtk3->main_quit; FALSE});
$window->signal_connect(key_press_event => \&killKey);
$window->signal_connect(
    scroll_event => 
        \&catchScroll, 
        [$style, $provider, $scrWin->get_vadjustment()]
);

$window->set_border_width(0);
$window->set_position(q<center>);
$window->fullscreen();
$window->set_decorated(FALSE);

$scrWin->add($tView);
$window->add($scrWin);
$window->show_all();

Gtk3->main;
```

the.css

```
text {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
    color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
}

textview {
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently I am not able to make the Pango font description to work either. Seems like it is difficult to find a good documentation of how this is supposed to work :)

Anyway, as a workaround, a CSS provider can be used:

```
sub setFontSize {
    my ($tView, $font_size) = @_;

    state $provider;

    my $context = $tView->get_style_context();
    if ( $provider ) {
         $context->remove_provider( $provider );
    }
    $provider = Gtk3::CssProvider->new();
    my $css = sprintf "textview {font-size: %spx;}", $font_size;
    $provider->load_from_data($css);
    $context->add_provider($provider, Gtk3::STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION);
}
```

Comment: Here's what I settled on.. I used CSS::Tiny to handle the css in the provider and I add functionality to freeze the vertical scroll bar while I modify font size with Ctrl+mouse wheel.

Comment: I updated the original post. I added the final version at the bottom.

Comment: For some reason I can't apply the font-size to `textview text {}` text CSS node in GTK, which should exists.